# Crystal reports subreport data should appear in the last page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report which has many sub reports. In one of the sub reports, there is a formula which says

`"if the text data is more than 500 charcters, it will spill over to the next page" .`

What I want to do is, if the data in the sub report exceeds 500 characters, it should apper on the last page of the report, not the next page. A new page should be generated at the end of the report and that data should appear on that page.

Comment: Place copy of that report into report footer and diplay these subreports conditionally - may work.

Answer (score 0):

one wayout would be:

1. Take the sub report in saperate section and force it to conditionally `supress` and `display` in last page.
2. Go to the section expert of the section and then to the formula editor.

   ```
   if (PageNumber=TotalPageCount)
   then true
   else false
   ```
3. Go to Section expert `Paging` tab there `X-2`of `New page Before`

   ```
   if (PageNumber=TotalPageCount)
   then true
   else false
   ```